# How can I make Netbeans compiler error messages more detailed?

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors

When I study Java, Netbeans' compiler error messages are not as detailed as Visual Studio's. For example, `Could not find symbol`. This is a very general message. Sometimes I am really struggling to find some bugs.

How can I make error messages more detailed?

Comment: I agree, sometimes error messages aren't very intuitive; it takes a bit of getting used to, but you tend to get the hang of it. Maybe if you give a specific example of a piece of code where you're encountering an error (read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), it'll make it easier for people to help you understand what it means, but changing the error messages from the Java compiler isn't something you can just configure easily...

Comment: These messages are not from Netbeans, they are from the Java compiler, and no, you cannot change them.

Comment: There are also ways around this. If you do proper exception handling, you can pinpoint where in the code may be an issue. Also, Netbeans usually links error messages to specific line numbers. Just click the underlined exception, and there's a chance it will take to the line that has an issue.

Comment: @A.Sharma Compiler error messages have nothing to do with exception handling. Compiler errors are not exceptions. Java compiler messages have nothing to do with NetBeans. You are hopelessly confused.